# JQuery. Выбор отдельных элемонтов с одинаковым классом.

Tags: jquery

Есть код jquery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".y").css({
        "height": $(".x").css("height")
    });
})(jQuery);
```

Принцип в том, чтобы .y назначалась высота .x. Но .x много, с разной высотой, и всем .y, которых столько же сколько и x, задается высота одного, видимо первого на странице, .x . Надо чтобы высота каждого .x задавалась соответствующему каждому .y. Как осуществить?

Answer (score 3):

1. Выбираем все необходимые элементы
2. Итерируем их
3. При каждой итерации находим соответствующий элемент и меняем высоту согласно этому элементу
4. Awesome!

.

```
var $yCollection = $(".y"); // это вы и без меня знаете
var $xCollection = $('.x');
$yCollection.each(function(index)) { //итерируем. Можно было бы и простым циклом, но не нужно. Аргумент index - позиция текущего элемента в общем списке.
    $(this).height($xCollection.eq(index).height()); // this - итерируемый DOM-элемент, eq(i) - выбрать в массиве элемент с индексом i
});
```